# GROUP BY and ORDER BY from different tables of CB extension as outcome to a list

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to implement this.

Table1 with subscriptions AS sub

> id, status, user_id, plan_id, parent_plan, parent_subscription

Table5 users (Joomla) AS u

> id

Table6 fields AS ue

> sub_region, country, state, city

```
(SELECT( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub.`plan_id`)
FROM `subscriptions` AS sub),
(SELECT  u.`id`
FROM `users` AS u),
(SELECT *
 FROM `fields` AS ue)),
WHERE sub.`user_id` = u.`id`
AND sub.`status` = 'A'),
ORDER BY FIELD(sub.`plan_id`,14,35,34,33,32,31,17,16,15,11,29,28,27,13,26,25,12,9,10,8,24,23,7,5,18,30,21,20,3,1,19,2))DESC, ue.`sub_region` ASC, ue.`country` ASC, ue.`state` ASC, ue.`city` ASC
```

Desired result is `parent_plan` in order 14, 11, 10, 18, 1 as below and each of the `parent_plan` group to show `plan_id` in order as follows:

For `parent_plan`=14 : 35,34,33,32,31,17,16,15

For `parent_plan`=11 : 29,28,27,13,26,25,12,9

For `parent_plan`=10 : 8,24,23,7,5

For `parent_plan`=18 : 30,21,20,3

For `parent_plan`=1 : 19,2

Then for each `parent_plan` group above, order `plan_id` as for instance if `parent_plan`=14 has 3 plans records with same `plan_id`=35 they will be ordered as ORDER BY `sub_region`, `country`, `state`, `city` ASC.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gi6vnWVYQddvXZt1vpxw2L/4)

Comment: Despite all of your attempts to clarify your requirements, plus the fact that I have read your question, fiddle and comments over 10 times; I have no idea what is broken.  I simply do not understand your needs.  I would help if I understood.  Maybe someone else can help you, or explain what you need to me.

Comment: Are you expecting 5 rows in your result set?  Can you perhaps explain why this new sql is not quite right? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gi6vnWVYQddvXZt1vpxw2L/8  Maybe if I guess a few different ways, you will be able to express the issue in a way that I understand.

Comment: All the queries you suggested, independently  work more than ok. The problem is the way they have to be structured as a subquery for CB. The list item of CB (Community Builder) has a tab for sorting that can be turned on to advanced mode and accept a subquery. The last subquery that I posted is the closest match that although produces results based on the parent_plan, the plan_ids are not ordered in the way the ORDER BY FIELD is instructing. If you notice, there is no ORDER BY statement. The Advanced tab accepts directly what we would put in the ORDER BY.

Comment: In any case I have implemented it another way by giving a seperate id to each plan (not changing the existing one) in the order that I want (as in ORDER BY FIELD). Then created a field that grabs these ids and put it in the Basic order of the Sorting tab (not the advanced) and that worked perfectly showing the plan_ids in order.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there are several aspects of your task that I am not fully understanding, but in terms of ordering the parent ids and the plan ids, I think I can offer some help.

I don't ever recommend using comma-syntax for JOINing tables -- it's just harder to read and maintain.

I'm not sure about the relevance of joining the users table, but I'll add that in and assume that you'll be able to modify the SELECT clause for your needs.

Raw SQL ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gi6vnWVYQddvXZt1vpxw2L/5))

```
SELECT sub.parent_plan,
       sub.plan_id
FROM subscriptions AS sub
JOIN users         AS u   ON sub.user_id = u.id
JOIN fields        AS ue  ON sub.user_id = ue.user_id
WHERE sub.status = 'A'
ORDER BY FIELD(sub.plan_id,14,35,34,33,32,31,17,16,15,11,29,28,27,13,26,25,12,9,10,8,24,23,7,5,18,30,21,20,3,1,19,2),
         ue.sub_region,
         ue.country,
         ue.state,
         ue.city
```

The following solution works so far but still the order is not perfect. It is an indication though on how to use it in the specific subquery of CB for anyone that might find it useful.

```
( SELECT FIELD(sub.`plan_id`, 14,35,34,33,32,31,17,16,15,11,29,28,27,13,26,25,12,9,10,8,24,23,7,5,18,30,21,20,3,1,19,2) AS pid
   FROM `subscriptions` AS sub
   WHERE sub.`plan_id` IN (14,35,34,33,32,31,17,16,15,11,29,28,27,13,26,25,12,9,10,8,24,23,7,5,18,30,21,20,3,1,19,2)
   AND sub.`user_id` = u.`id`
   AND sub.`status` = 'A' 
   LIMIT 1),
       ue.`region` ASC,
       ue.`country` ASC,
       ue.`state` ASC,
       ue.`city` ASC
```

Comment: I think there is too much I don't understand about your task to help you.  Why do you need a result set that is a single string?  I don't understand what needs to be altered.